# React + Firebase – Update the increment state of Like/Clap button to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/adamschwarcz/react-firebase-app

I am really new to react and firebase and I followed [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/intro-firebase-react/) to come up with [this app (full project – github link here)](https://github.com/adamschwarcz/react-firebase-app) – it's an "Add your Wish app"

My problem is that I cannot store clap count on each post to my firebase – this component is called LikeButton.js.

I have been trying to add some similar firebase code (handleChange, handleSubmit, componentDidMount... etc.. etc..) as I learned in the tutorial to LikeButton.js to store the total amount of counts in firebase each time the button is clicked and the amount of claps incremented by +1.

Simply what I want – everytime the clap button is clicked and the initial ('0') state of count is incremented to +1 the current count is going to be updated into the database.

Just cannot come up with solution, can somebody please help?

My LikeButton.js code without any firebase:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from '../../firebase.js';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import './Like.css';

class LikeButton extends Component {


  state = {
    count: 0,
  }

  incrementLike = () => {
    let newCount = this.state.count + 1
    this.setState({
      count: newCount
    })

    console.log(this.state.count);
  } 

  render() {
    return(

      <div class="counter">

        <Button type="submit" color="primary" onChange={this.handleCount} onClick={this.incrementLike}>{this.state.count} </Button>

      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default LikeButton
```

My Add.js code with firebase:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from '../../firebase.js';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FadeIn from "react-fade-in";
import Placeholder from '../Placeholder/Placeholder.js';
import LikeButton from '../Like/Like.js'
import './Add.css';


class Add extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          loading: true,
          currentItem: '',
          username: '',
          items: []
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
      }

      handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
        const item = {
          title: this.state.currentItem,
          user: this.state.username
        }
        itemsRef.push(item);
        this.setState({
          currentItem: '',
          username: ''
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {

        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), 1500);
        });

        const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
        itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
          let items = snapshot.val();
          let newState = [];
          for (let item in items) {
            newState.push({
              id: item,
              title: items[item].title,
              user: items[item].user
            });
          }
          this.setState({
            items: newState
          });
        });
      }

      removeItem(itemId) {
        const itemRef = firebase.database().ref(`/items/${itemId}`);
        itemRef.remove();
      }


    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
        <div className="wrap">
            <section className="add-item">
                <h1>Napíš svoj wish</h1> 
                <h3>Možno prilepíš sebe, možno posunieš firmu.</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <TextField 
                        id="filled-required" 
                        label="Meno" 
                        name="username" 
                        variant="filled"
                        value={this.state.username} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />


                    <TextField
                        required
                        id="standard-multiline-flexible"
                        label="Tvoje prianie"
                        name="currentItem"
                        variant="filled"
                        multiline
                        rows="6"
                        rowsMax="8"
                        value={this.state.currentItem}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />

                    <Button 
                      type="submit"
                      variant="contained" 
                      color="primary">
                      Poslať wish
                    </Button>
                </form>

            </section>

            <section className='items-list'>
                <div className="item">
                    <div>
                        {this.state.items.map((item) => {
                            return (
                            <div>
                            {this.state.loading ? (
                              <>
                                <FadeIn>
                                <Placeholder />
                                </FadeIn>
                              </>
                            ) : (
                            <div className="wish" key={item.id}>
                                <FadeIn>
                                  <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                  <div className="name">
                                      <p>poslal <span>{item.user}</span></p>
                                      <LikeButton />
                                  </div>
                                </FadeIn>
                            </div>
                            )}
                            </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Add
```

Comment: What is the `handleCount` referenced in the `onChange` prop of your button in the first code block?

Comment: It might be a code that I didn't delete from my first attempts of connecting it to the database

Comment: Are you asking how you would go about updating an element in Firebase from the `LikeButton` component? If so, I would encourage you to take a look at the Firebase Real-Time DB docs for writing data https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write]

Comment: What LikeButton component does is that after you click on it – it increments the like/clap count state to +1 everytime it is clicked. I want the number of claps (state count) to be always updated into realtime fire database so it keeps track of how many claps does the wish have.

Comment: here by you can see the full app in codesandbox – https://codesandbox.io/s/github/adamschwarcz/react-firebase-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to tell the `LikeComponent` which `Wish` it will be updating, and you will also need to be able to access the `clapCount` of the wish from the `LikeComponent`. This can be done easily using `props`. You should re-configure `LikeComponent` to accept a prop similar to `wish`, which would be the wish that you are displaying and modifying.

So, this line in `Add.js`
`<LikeButton />`
would instead look like `<LikeButton wish={item} />`. This way, your `LikeComponent` can access the `item`/`wish`.

Next, in the `LikeComponent`, you need to remove the local state and instead use the clap count stored in Firebase. Luckily, since you're passing the `wish` via a `prop`, you can simply refactor the `LikeComponent` to look like this:

```
class LikeButton extends Component {
  incrementLike = () => {
    // TODO: Implement clap incrementation via Firebase updates
  } 

  render() {
    return(
      <div class="counter">
        <Button type="submit" color="primary" onClick={this.incrementLike}>{this.props.wish.clapCount} </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Next, we need to actually implement `incrementLike`. Luckily, since we are getting the `wish` item passed to us via the `wish` prop, we can easily update it like so:

```
incrementLike = () => {
    // get a reference to the item we will be overwriting
    const wishRef = firebase.database().ref(`/items/${this.props.wish.id}`);

    // get the current value of the item in the database
    wishRef.once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            // get the value of the item. NOTE: this is unsafe if the item 
            // does not exist
            let updatedWish = snapshot.val();
            // update the item's desired property to the desired value
            updatedWish.clapCount = updatedWish.clapCount + 1;
            // replace the item with `wish.id` with the `updatedWish`
            wishRef.set(updatedWish);
        });
}
```

While this should work with only a few tweaks, I'm sure there's a better way to do it. You might even be able to avoid the call to `once('value')` since you're passing `wish` as a prop to `LikeComponent`. You should play around with it.

However, I strongly encourage you to explore migrating to Firebase Cloud Firestore. It's API is way more straightforward (in my opinion) than Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks!! With just few some adjustments in Add.js and LikeButton.js I was able to run the app as planned!